# Proper format for using a string in a concatenation in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, concatenation, acl

I am seeking a way to use a string in a concatenation. For starters i have an acl in which i need to get the module that is being passed. 
So I use this:

```
$modules = $request->getModuleName();
$modules = ucfirst ($modules);
```

This returns the proper module. 
The part i am having issues with is the concatenation string.
So i have this:

```
$authModel=new Default_Model_Auth();
```

"Default" needs to be replaced with $modules. I have tried a couple different things they are below but none have worked

```
$authModel=new $modules._Model_Auth();
$authModel=new $modules . _Model_Auth();
$authModel=new $modules.'_'._Model_Auth();
```

The first and second one errors out with `Fatal error: Class 'Default' not found` - 
and the third one - it does not show anything.

Is this possible to do? I looked on the net but i may be naming the issue wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_Model_Auth` is not a string. You can only concatenate strings. This should work:

```
$auth_class = $modules . '_Model_Auth';
$authModel = new $auth_class();
```